# How to draw navigation related images over the map image in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, image, image-processing

I am trying to develop a navigation application using c# winforms. I am using an image control for show a map. Now I want to be able to draw some navigation related shapes over this map. Specifically I want to be able to draw

- Different types of lines (Dotted, Solid, and dashed). This is to show different paths
- A blinking mark to show the current position on the map.

I also want to be able to remove part of these shapes. For example in case of a wrong move I will show it a solid red line but after taking the correct move the solid red line has to be removed.

I have tried changing the image in code and when needed getting a fresh copy from the source image but it seems there will be a better way to solve this problem. One possibility I am thinking is to somehow have two images one for the map and one for showing the navigation marks by creating an image at run time and then overlap each other but dont know exactly what to do. Please suggest.

Comment: Since you have dynamic elements in play, you'd be betteroff drawing "on top" of the image in the Paint() event of the control housing the image.  Store the "state" (what should be drawn) in class level variables so it can be accessed in the Paint() event.  To "erase" (or change) elements you'd then change what is stored at class level and then call the Refresh() method of the image container to cause it to update with the new information.  Be sure to use the Graphics supplied in the Paint() via `e.Graphics`; do **NOT** use CreateGraphics() in the Paint() event...

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion for a small blinking circle on the image.

Comment: You'd simply use a Boolean to track whether the circle should be visible and take that into account in the Paint() event.  Then use a Timer() with a reasonable Interval() to toggle the Boolean and call Refresh() to force the Paint() event to fire again.